# Grammar for If ,Else if and else statement in ANTLR3

Tags: grammar, antlr3

I tried the following grammar in antlr3 :

```
ifstmt  : IF '(' relation ')' (stmt|block)
        (ELSEIF '(' relation')' (stmt|block))*
        (ELSE (stmt|block))?
        ;
```

But it is not accepting the else part which says:
"EXPECTED ELSE IF INSTEAD OF ELSE":

```
if(a>b) stat; else if(a<b) stat; else stat;
```

And while interpreting the grammar with antlrworks, it says:

```
  rule ifstmt has non-LL(*) decision due to recursive rule invocations reachable
from alts 1,2.  Resolve by left-factoring or using syntactic predicates or using        backtrack=true option.
```

If anyone could suggest acceptable grammar for if-elseif-else statment, it would be great.

Comment: Have you considered using ANTLR 4? The new algorithm is not subject to the same restriction you described above.

Comment: I am bound to use ANTLR3. Is there any way to solve this problem using v3